# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method

Tags: javascript, callback, this, google-visualization, self

```
    var resultItemView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        render : function(){            
            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["table"], callback: function() {       
                     var self = this;       
                     this._drawVisualization(self);
            }});
        },

       _drawVisualization : function(self){ 
           var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            //Here i'm creating data table  ...

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(self.$el.find("#graphDiv"));
            chart.draw(data, null, null);               

       },
       return resultItemView;
   });
```

At render function google visualization is being loaded and in callback function drawVisualization is being called. Also i'm passing "this" object to this function as a parameter.To do this i used an anonymous function. In drawVisualization function self is equal to this "this" object. But i'm getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method '_drawVisualization'". What am i doing wrong? How can i correct it? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put `var self = this;` outside of the call to `google.load`.

```
   var resultItemView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        render : function(){     
            var self = this;       
            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["table"], callback: function() {       

                     self._drawVisualization(self);
            }});
        },
```

This is because the anonymous function you pass as a callback parameter to `google.load` will be called without specifying a `this` context - so that will be the global (window) object.
Inside of your `render` function, you will have the correct `this` and can store that in a variable `self` to refer to it in your callback function.

**EDIT:**
Also, if you do this, you do not need to pass the `this` context to the `_drawVisualization` method anymore. Complete Example:

```
    var resultItemView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        render : function(){   
            var self = this;          
            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["table"], callback: function() {       
                self._drawVisualization();
            }});
        },

       _drawVisualization : function(){ 
           var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            //Here i'm creating data table  ...

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(this.$el.find("#graphDiv"));
            chart.draw(data, null, null);               

       },
       return resultItemView;
   });
```